# Using db_select, how can I select all nodes with any of an array of taxonomy terms and order by the number of terms it is associated with?

Tags: database

I have this so far:

```
// for example, $tags = array(2, 8, 18);
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'post')
  ->condition('n.status', 1);
$query->join('field_data_field_tags', 'tags', 'tags.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->condition('tags.field_tags_tid', $tags, 'IN');
```

I need to order these results by the number of "tags" associated with each node.

I've tried many things, using addExpression() with count() statements, then an orderBy(), etc, but I can't get it right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: orderBy() should work ? what problems have u faced while using addExpression(), count() statements and orderBy() ? PLs mention it

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure exactly how to use expressions in SQL.  I tried adding this to my above code:

`$query->addExpression('SELECT count(*) FROM {taxonomy_index} ti WHERE ti.nid=n.nid', 'num_tags');
$query->orderBy('num_tags', 'DESC');`

Comment: @user724228 please edit your last comment into question.

Comment: The question remains the original at the top: how can I order nodes by the number of terms associated with it?  The code I tried in my above comment gives the error "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(*) FROM taxonomy_index ti WHERE ti.nid=n.nid AS num_tags FROM node'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.  Following is the code I used to generate the query:

```
// for example, $tags = array(2, 8, 18);
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'post')
  ->condition('n.status', 1);
$query->join('field_data_field_tags', 'tags', 'tags.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->condition('tags.field_tags_tid', $tags, 'IN');
$query->addExpression('count(tags.entity_id)', 'num_tags');
$query->groupBy('nid');
$query->orderBy('num_tags', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put count as alias name in the count(*) and then groupby clause can be used on that column.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->addExpression('COUNT(n.nid)', 'count'); // addExpression
   $query->condition('n.type', 'post')
      ->condition('n.status', 1);
    $query->join('field_data_field_tags', 'tags', 'tags.entity_id = n.nid');   
    $query->condition('tags.field_tags_tid', $tags, 'IN');
    $query->groupBy('count', 'DESC'); //count is column name given in the addExpression
```

Comment: That gives the error: 

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1056 Can't group on 'count'